# White space on left side of page using CSS only layout

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have searched and cant seem to quite get what i need to do to get rid of the white space on the right side. If someone can help me figure out what to do and please explain why, i would appreciate it. Here is a link to my project.

[Project Site](http://198.176.185.250/classes/135stu14/assignments/CSSlayout/index.html)

Comment: You mean the whitespace on the **right** side, right? _Joseph_'s answer is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of `background-repeat: no-repeat` on the body style.

(index.css line 11)

Comment: Thanks guys. As if i dont feel stupid enough. I actually did that, but was refreshing the web link instead of my notepad++ preview. So nothing was changing.... I need sleep. Again, thanks lol.

Comment: @mogieL np. happens to us all :P

Comment: @mogieL if someone has helped you solve your issue, you will want to accept their answer. :)